# Minimum number of vertices the connected graph should have.

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

What is the minimum number of vertices should the graph have such that

1. Edge connectivity of graph is 5
2. Point connectivity of graph is 3
3. Minimum degree of each vertex is 7.

I found a graph which has 14 vertex and satisfies the above condition. (Two Complete-7 graph connected by 5 edges at 3 vertex). Can we find a graph with lesser vertex. Prove or disprove.

Comment: Are those 3 different exercises or is it one single graph satisfying **all** 3 conditions?

Comment: It is a single graph that has all 3 properties.